# '\n' tag automatically added while pushing string to an array

Tags: typescript

In my program, I have the following loop-

```
this.storeData.StudentList.forEach(pStudent => {
  studentName +=  pStudent.Name + '\n'
});
console.log(studentName);
array.push(studentName);
console.log(array);
```

While I'm printing the 'studentName' variable, I'm perfectly getting the new line added to the string. But when I'm printing the 'array', it is showing like 'Student1\nStudent2\n'. What is the problem here? I'm using typescript 3.1.6.

Comment: This is just about how the console display things. Nothing is wrong here. It would be so messy if displaying an array with multiple strings, each with multiple line break.

Answer (score 2):

If you log `studentName` (i.e. `console.log(studentName)`) then it would indeed be a new new line.

But since you are logging `array` (i.e. `console.log(array)`) you are seeing the stringified version of an array and in this case `\n` is preserved.

## More

Example:

[image]